# Vacuum as a physical/chemical/material substance

Tags: vacuum, aether

Can the vacuum be understood as a physical/chemical/material substance?

Remark: Vacuum has a density energy (so it has a density "mass" equivalence due to $E=mc^2$). Vacuum is quantum (but not classically!) polarizable (vacuum polarization effects are essential in QED or QCD).

Remark (II): A chemical substance is a form of matter that has constant chemical composition and characteristic properties.It can be solid, liquid, gas, or plasma. If vacuum is some kind of "substance" with some "physical" constant features (like density energy, polarizability,...), we can understand from elementary QFT principles that every particle is excitation from "a ground" state. Should we understand the SM as the vacuum composition or "states" at certain energy ranges ("temperature") just as a solid, liquid or gas (even a plasma) are just states at certain "temperature"?

Remark (III): Vacuum has "a structure" or "features" just as the state of matter show certain properties at certain temperatures. Is this just a useless analogy?

Comment: You may want to look at this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a space-filling medium, is not new. The idea dates back to the time of Maxwell and ElectroMagnetic waves. Back in the day, Maxwell calculated the speed of light, but eventually the question was raised: *this speed is relative to what?* So they considered a space-filling substance or field, thought to be necessary as a transmission medium for the propagation of electromagnetic or gravitational forces, called [aether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories)

However, experiments proved that this medium has to be really weird, so Einstein concluded it's not even necessary; and questioned its whole existence.

Anyway, current particle theories have many space-filling fields, e.g. the famous [Higgs field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_field_%28classical%29). But, note these fields may sometimes be far different from normal matter(Fermionic fields).

Comment: I will add more to this answer, if I find some time later.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - Yes.

See https://asunow.asu.edu/20170208-finding-nothing-conversation-frank-wilczek for details.